# SetOnClickListener in ListView

Tags: android, .net, xamarin.android

Good morning, I implemented a `listView` that has some information that is hidden, and a button, however I am having trouble with the click event of the button, I'm using MonoDroid, I implemented the interface `OnClickListener ()`, my problem is that if I set the `button.setOnclickListener (new MyClassClick ())` inside the `ListView` adapter it creates an object each time the `ListView` is scrolled, and can not reuse the previously created object, it is possible to check if the button already has an action linked to he? type a `GetOnclickListener ()`?

public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

```
        var item = produtos[position];
        ViewHolderProdutos viewHolder;
        var view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
        {
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ProdutoListItem,parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.Inicializa(view);
            view.Tag = viewHolder;
        }
        ProductsBase prod = (ProductsBase) productList[position];
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.Tag;
        viewHolder.Bind(prod);
        var btnIncluir = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnIncluir);
        //Evento Click do Botão Incluir
        btnIncluir.SetOnClickListener(new OnClickButton(productList[position].pro_codigo.ToString(), parent.Context));
        return view;
```

}

Sorry if the text is confused, my English is not good

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problme, but you can keep a reference to your new ClassClick, and if it is already initialised, you have nothing to do.

Comment: Can you post some sample code - it's not clear to me what you're problem is from the description.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Adapter`s `GetView` method you need to only set the `OnClickListener` when `convertView` is `null`.

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var view = convertView;

    if (null == view)
    {
        //1. inflate or create your views here
        //2. Set OnClickListeners
    }

    //populate views with Adapter item data
}
```